# Python guessing 2 numbers game

Tags: python

**Question is**

Write a program that prints to the user the sum (a+b) and product (a*b) of two randomly generated natural numbers (positive integers) between 1 and 100. To win the game the user must guess the two numbers, the order of the guess should not matter. The user is given three guesses, if they are wrong after three guesses then the numbers are revealed to them. The user has to guess both guesses correctly in a single round and is not told if one of the numbers in a previous round was correct.
The user has 3 attempts to guess the two numbers, and the game should finish if the user guesses the numbers correctly.

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,100)
b = random.randint(1,100)

print("Sum of two random number is",a + b)
print("Product of two random number is", a * b)
print("Try to guess the 2 numbers that make this sum and product, you have 3 tries, good luck!")

count = 0
win = 0

while count != 3:
    guess_a = int(input('Guess first number '))
    guess_b = int(input('Guess second number '))
    
    if count == 3:
        break
        
    if ((guess_a == a) or (guess_b == b)) and ((guess_b == a) or (guess_a == b)):
        win = 1
        break
        
    else:
        count = count + 1
        print('Incorrect!!!')

if win == 1:
    print('Congrats you won the game.')
    
else:
    print('You lost the game.')
    print('Number a was:',a)
    print('Number b was',b)
```

I tried this it kinda works, but I don't know how to make it that the order of the guessed numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: Try: `((guess_a == a) and (guess_b == b)) or ((guess_b == a) and (guess_a == b))`

Comment: use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set): `{guess_a, guess_b} == {a, b}`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist what if a and b happened to be the same?

Comment: the set soln is very neat.  If a and b are the same it will still work, try it out, you then need to enter identical numbers to be correct. By the way, any one with some rudimentary math skill doesn't need to "guess" the answer ;-)

Comment: @rajah9 `{3, 3} == {3, 3}` is `True`. or what do you think will not work?

Comment: ok, Tried it out, and it works. I see that the sets will only contain one element and `{3, 3} == {3}`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to not use booleans at all.

Since `0` is automatically converted to `False` in an conditional statement, we can just make an expression that equals `0` if a certain condition is true.

The expression I came up with is:

```
is_guess_a_right = (a - guess_a) * (a - guess_b)
is_guess_b_right = (b - guess_a) * (b - guess_b)
are_both_right = is_guess_a_right + is_guess_b_right
```

If the final expression is equal to zero, then both expressions are correct, in otherwords, guess_a and guess_b are equal to a and b (since `a - guess_a` would be equal to zero if they are the same).

Final code:

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 100)
b = random.randint(1, 100)

print("Sum of a and b is %s" % (a + b))
print("Product of a and b is %s" % (a * b))
print("You have three tries to guess the numbers")

count = 0

while count < 3:
    guess_a = int(input("Guess the first number: "))
    guess_b = int(input("Guess the second number: "))

    lose = (guess_a - a) * (guess_a - b) + (guess_b - a) * (guess_b - b)

    if lose:
        print("Try again")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Congrats, you won the game")
        print("The two numbers were %s and %s" % (a, b))
        break
```